# How can I find tesseract.exe path with C#?

Tags: c#, directory, path, tesseract

How can I find path for tesseract.exe?

I tried this, but it has not found it, I used it for python.exe before with success:

```
var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            string myPath = null;
            foreach (var p in path.Split(new char[] { ';' }))
            {
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(p, "tesseract.exe");
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    myPath = fullPath;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (myPath != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myPath);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Couldn't find myPath on %PATH%");
            }
```

So I tried:

```
var allExePaths =
                from drive in Environment.GetLogicalDrives()
                from exePath in Directory.GetFiles(drive, "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                select exePath;
```

but it throws an error: Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied

Comment: Why does your second code look for `*.exe` and not `tesseract.exe`? You need to trap exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetFullPath(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
        return Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

    var values = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    foreach (var path in values.Split(Path.PathSeparator))
    {
        var fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
            return fullPath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It does not return anything. My tesseract.exe was installed in C:/ProgramFiles/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe

Comment: @juraj14466 Is `tesseract.exe` a command line program or a Windows GUI program? Installations add to the `PATH` environment variable when they expect to be used from the command line which is generally not GUI programs.

Comment: I installed it as python package pytesseract